# DoctrineModule "reflection exception" in ZF2

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

Working with the Zend Framework 2 application skeleton, I have installed DoctrineModule and DoctrineORMModule according to the instructions.  I am getting this error when trying to execute the doctrine.php command line tool.  (FYI I do not get the error if I uninstall DoctrineORMModule)

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ReflectionException' with message 'Class Doctrine\DBAL\Connection does not exist'...
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `ReflectionException` indicates that the class can't be found. Possibly something wrong with autoload_classmap.php which tells the autoloader where to find the classes.

Comment: Development of zf2 and DoctrineModule are moving quite quickly. Composer is now the recomended install method, and works very nicely. Updating to the most recent versions with Composer may solve your problems.